# When are big-list questions not opinioned-based?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, big-list

The question [Are there visual illustrations on the struggle of Word on formatting in comparing with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/712014/50146) is closed for being opinion-based. How is it be different to the rest of [big-list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-list) questions?

See also: [Do we follow StackExchange rules?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4256/50146)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `[big-list]` questions tend to be either showing equally-valid approaches with some critiera (e.g. [the IDE one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides)), or  demos of (La)TeX concepts which have some 'artistic' element (e.g. [Big list of beautifully typeset package documentations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/509692/big-list-of-beautifully-typeset-package-documentations)). In the first case, the reader can use the criteria to choose the answer they like best. In the latter, the 'sales pitch' is for people *already using (La)TeX*.

The issue with [Are there visual illustrations on the struggle of Word on formatting in comparing with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/712014/are-there-visual-illustrations-on-the-struggle-of-word-on-formatting-in-comparin,). to me, is that it's about Word vs LaTeX. That makes it opinion-based - comparison with non-TeX software is a matter of opinion that's out-of-scope, as anyone reading the site should assume we have already made that judgement.

At the same time, I don't see that it would really *work* as a big-list question - but that's a secondary thing.

Comment: hmm, while I still want to have illustrations on Word's deficits, how about changing the question to "illustrations of how complicate elements be produced in LaTeX"? The emphasis is not on the final product, but the ability for the author to focus on the content while be confident that they will get what they mean

Comment: Hi, I wonder if you still have interest in this topic?

Comment: @Ooker We have a showcase big list of impressive typography

Answer (score 3):

Well already the title of your question was opinion based: You asked only about struggles in Word with the implicit assumption that LaTeX is "struggle free" and that you are looking for some nice "Word bashing" examples. But a fair "big list" comparision should also show the things that are easier in a text processor.

Comment: I agree this is one-side. But, wouldn't that fair big list be able to split into a "Word bashing" list and "Word praising" list? So the fix is simple: ask another question on where Word is struggle free!